# supress output of a python method if it loops more than once in a for loop

Tags: python, rest

I  have  a python function  which uses  GET  call  for REST  API.
  This  function needs  to run in a  `for` loop. How to prevent it from  outputting more than  once in the console  without preventing it from actually running
Here  is   the class   method:

```
def get_all_saleable_clusters(self):
    all_seller_response = self.ism_session.get_seller_info()
    self.seller_list = [item.get('sellerId') for item in 
                all_seller_response if item.get('sellerId')== i ]
    self.sellerid_in_test =''.join(self.seller_list)
    self.logger.info('SUCCESS..... Get all sellers_ api\n')
```

Comment: I would  rather  reframe  the  question  as  how  to  suppress HTTP GET  output  in console output.  The process  mentioned in [link](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/10/25/temporarily-suppress-console-output-in-python/)  does not seem to be working for HTTP GET  output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but using `self` suggests that your method is within a class, so you could set a counter on `__init__`:

```
class MyClass
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
```

Afterwards in `get_all_saleable_clusters`:

```
if self.cnt == 0:
    # print it to the console
    # increment the counter
    self.cnt += 1
```

In the second call the condition won't be fulfilled anymore.

Comment: This  would  stop the  method from execution at all. Is there a  way to execute it but prevent console output  from appearing more than once

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `break` where you need the for loop to exit and stop looping.